# Windows 8 upgrade installer is not working properly

Tags: windows-8

Windows 8 upgrade installer is not working properly, every time I try to download the OS there is an error "The download task is not complete"  "The specified service does not exist as an installed service". I already paid for it, it is pretty irritating that Something I paid for is not letting me install the services it provides. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service" Try enabling the BITS service, WebClient service and Windows Update service; I suspect you have one of them not being able to start so that might be a first thing to troubleshoot. Tell me if it worked so I can put it as an answer. I really suspect it to be BITS because it's talking about a "download task" and that's kind of what BITS [does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service), although its named Jobs there, but that shouldn't matter...

Comment: I don't know how to enable the bits service.

Comment: Start > Run > Services.msc > Double click BITS and set it to Automatic, then click Start, then Apply.

Comment: I set bits to automatic then ran the installer again, yet it still gives me the same error.

Comment: "I set bits to automatic" but is the status column showing "Running"? also check the other services Tom suggested.

Comment: I set bits and webclient to run automatically and start, how do I set the windows update service?

Comment: I had a similar issue with one of the customers System while Upgrading the windows..And yes Tom is right its something to do with BITS.But i figured out just enabling would not resolve the issue so i decided to run a small fix that i made for windows 7 which register few dll's and some services and it worked fine afterwords.The tool is similar to Dail-a-fix for Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Redownload the Windows 8 [Upgrade Assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8). Your download may have been corrupt.